# Model with wrong property types

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework. I started with database first approach which created my classes corresponding to the tables I selected. I am using **WPF**. Unfortunately there is a problem occurred while EF6 was mapping classes. The assigned type for a field is **byte** while in some cases the value exceeds the byte constraints. So, I want to replace it with either int or double. How do I change the model field types without any changes made for the used database?

```
namespace DataChrome{
  public partial class REGISTRY_MEST{
    public byte MEST { get; set; } //Wrong typed field 
    public string MESTNAME { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> IDSTRAT { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> MESTOLD { get; set; }
  }
```

}

Comment: Since it's database first, can't you just change the database?

Comment: Yes! as per suggestion of @Stefan you need to update datatype in DB table & update Model in your project because you are using db first approach. Thanks

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a possibility to change the init db. I'm wandering if there is any alternative option?

Answer (score 1):

So, giving 7 hours to this problem I found the right solution. All you need is just to set user mapping  rules in appconfig file. For more details: [visit this page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/InstallManagedConfig.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The type change should be possible by editing the edmx model: click the `MEST` property of the class inside the edmx model, then set the Type accordingly in the Properties Window and save the model.

You are running a risk by doing this, as it might be possible to store a value too big for the column if you just change the type this way. You noted that you are using Oracle as the underlying DB, so it might very well be the case that EF generated a "wrong" type for that property.

If you are absolutely sure that the DB will accept the expanded type (int, double) then it should be safe to edit the property as I mentioned at the start. Otherwise you would have to change the DB and generate the class anew - you might need to delete the class from the model and add it again, because not all changes to the table are picked up by the automatic update process.

Comment: Can you please point  out exactly which class properties should I use? It's not that clear from the comment you've given